# global name 'load_jpeg' is not defined

Tags: python, class, pygame

I keep getting this error whilst loading my program global name 'load_jpeg' is not defined
when running **my class code.**

```
class Hero:
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x=x
        self.y=y
        self.width=70
        self.height=70
        self.image = pygame.image.load('ezio.jpg')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
```

Comment: Why do you expect `load_jpeg` to be defined? Did you import it? Pygame doesn't define such a function, in any case.

Comment: You can't write functions and expect them to implement themselves.

Comment: i thought it would import an image from my python folder

Comment: @TobiAkinyemi: I think you are looking for [`pygame.image.load()`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html#pygame.image.load), but you still need to import that first.

Comment: i have the class in another bit of coding that is meant to call upon the variable

Comment: I have changed the self.image variable to self.image = pygame.image.load('ezio.jpg') however how would i call upon it, because pygame.blit doesnt work for me when i try it.

Comment: You should edit your entire question for your new problem with `pygame.blit()`

Answer (score 0):

The fact that `pygame.blit()` did not work is very clear and same with `load_jpeg`. First, the `load_jpeg` error. Just like how Martijn Pieters said, you can't just create a function that Python did not originally have. Maybe you could have wrote a specific function with that name, but that is not the case. Second, the `pygame.blit()`. To use this function, you need two arguments inside of it. To be able to do that, you might want to change your class:

```
class Hero(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
  def __init__(self, location, image_file):
    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
    self.rect.top, self.rect.left = location  #The equivalent as self.x and self.y
    self.width = 70
    self.height = 70
    self.image = pygame.image.load(image_file)
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
```

And add this line (if you haven't done this already and outside your class and before your while loop):

```
Heroes = Hero([100, 100], 'ezio.jpg')
```

This creates an variable that can be used for the `pygame.blit()` function. It is usually more better to do `self.rect.top, self.rect.left = location` than defining `self.x` and `self.y`. It is usually more of a PyGame style with rects. It looks like you are going to `__init__` this into a sprite and  define `self`. After you have done this, `pygame.blit()` should work. Saying that the variable name of the class is *x*, you must always do it in this order:

```
pygame.blit(x.image, x.rect)
```

With `x.image` first, then `x.rect` after. In your case, that line should look like:

```
pygame.blit(Heroes.image, Heroes.rect) #Assuming the variable name is Heroes
```

This answer should cancel  your error and make the `pygame.blit()` function working again. I hope this helps you!